# What are the git commands for the following steps?

Tags: git

I've created a branch `A` from master branch and checked out this branch, and worked in directory `subdir_x` only for a long time.

I will use the following steps to update master branch via pull request.

1. Copy `subdir` (only the added and updated files) to a temporary location, e.g. `/tmp/subdir_x`.

```
    cp /path/to/..../subdir_x /tmp/subdir -r  # then remove unchanged files
```

2. Create a branch `B` from master branch

```
    git checkou B
```

3. Checkout `B`, copy `/tmp/subdir_x` to `subdir_x` (overwrite the old files)

```
    cp /tmp/subdir_x /path/to/..../subdir_x -r
```

> (The pull request merging shows that it will revert some (not all) changes of some files not in `subdir_x`, very strange)

4. Commit and push (then create Pull Request `B` -> `master`)

Are there any git commands which can be helpful in this case?

---

For example, I have the following files.

```
dir1/
    file1
    dir2/
        file2
dir3/
    file3
dirx/
    dirx1/
        filex1  # updated
        filex2  # no change
        dirx11/
            filex11  # no chnage
            filex12  # added
dir4/
```

I created a branch `A` from master, and have been working in `dirx`. And created a lot of commits. And filex1 was updated and filex12 was added. (At the same time, other people may have changed/added files and committed and merged to master)

Now I create a branch `B` from master, I want to apply all the commits (updated filex1 and added filex12) to `B`.

Comment: You describe steps and say "how do I fix?" Can you show what happens at each step (minimal example with one file modified, one not modified), and explain what the problem is, exactly?

Comment: Can you also add what u expect as the end result ? Do u want two branch with the changes ??

Comment: You have a lot of typos in your commands. Working through a concrete [MCVE] made just for this question will help you get rid of them

Comment: @MadPhysicist, the approach I will use has a lot of manual step and it seems not very "git".

Comment: @ca9163d9. Agreed. Now make a [mcve] showing what you're actually doing.

Comment: This question has been updated with an example, I hope it's a bit clearer now.

Comment: Sounds like you want `git rebase B`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a PR (Pull Request) in progress for B, and A has new commits, all you need to do (assuming you are alone working on B) is:

```
git switch B
git rebase A # resolve potential merge conflicts there
git push --force
```

That will update your current PR, which will include all A commits and current B commits (now replayed on top of A)

Comment: The problem is, in the PR from A -> B, there are some changes on files not in `dirx` (it will undo some commits done by other people, strange). in Branch A, it changed only the files in dirx. Can I exclude some changes after `git rebase A` ?

Comment: @ca9163d9 Try the rebase first, to see if indeed those files end up mssing.